# UI Tests for iCloud dependent features

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, icloud

iCloud sync works fine in simulator - I launch simulator, log in into my apple account, then launch my app and it perfectly syncs - this is the way I test and debug iCloud dependent features.

I'd like to bring iCloud testing to another level and write some automated tests to make them a part of my CI process.

Is there any way I can launch simulator logged in into specific Apple account or log in right from my tests? (I reset simulators before each tests run so manual preconfiguration is not an option for me)